# the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'am having a simple code for filter tgl from table tbl_permintaan.

When I'am click Cari appears error

> Query permintaan salah : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1

and a code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker-examples14').Zebra_DatePicker({
        format: 'Y-m-d'
    });
    $('#datepicker-examples15').Zebra_DatePicker({
        format: 'Y-m-d'
    });
});
</script>
<br><br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
    Laporan Permintaan Bulanan
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form action="?page=Permintaan-bulanan" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label">Dari tangal</label>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker-examples14" name="mulai">
            </div>
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label">Sampai tangal</label>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker-examples15" name="akhir">
            </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnCari" value="Cari">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Identitas</th>
            <th>Nama Kegiatan</th>
            <th>Kegiatan</th>
            <th>Banyak</th>
            <th>Tanggal</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST["btnCari"])){
        $mulai = $_POST["mulai"];
        $akhir = $_POST["akhir"];

        $userSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_permintaan INNER JOIN tbl_kegiatan ON id_kegiatan = id_k INNER JOIN tbl_souvenir ON id_souvenir = id_s INNER JOIN tbl_loker ON id_loker = pt_pengirim WHERE tgl BETWEEN '".$_POST['mulai']."' AND '".$_POST['akhir']."' LIMIT $hal, $row";
        $userQry = mysql_query($userSql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query permintaan salah : ".mysql_error());
        while ($userRow = mysql_fetch_array($userQry)) {
        $nomor = 1;
        $Kode = $userRow['id_permintaan'];
        $banyak = $userRow['banyak']+$userRow['bkedua']+$userRow['bketiga']+$userRow['bkeempat']+$userRow['bkelima']+$userRow['brosur_banyak'];
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $nomor; ?></td>
            <td><small>Nama <b><?php echo $userRow['nama_pengirim']; ?></b>, dari <b><?php echo $userRow['nama_loker']; ?></b></small></td>
            <td><small><?php echo $userRow['nama_kegiatan']; ?></small></td>
            <td><small>Kegiatan <?php echo $userRow['nm_kegiatan']; ?></small></td>
            <td><small><?php echo $banyak; ?></small></td>
            <td><small><?php echo $userRow["tgl"];?></small></td>
            <td><small><?php
            if($userRow['stts']==1){
                echo '<a href="?page=Edit-Permintaan&amp;Kode='.$Kode.'" target="_self" title="Edit Permintaan"><span class="label label-info">Pending</span></a>';
            }elseif($userRow['stts']==2)
            {
                echo '<span class="label label-success">Diterima</span>';
            }elseif ($userRow['stts']==0) {
                echo '<span class="label label-danger">Ditolak</span>';
            }
            ?></small></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php
        $nomor++;}}
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$userSql` to see how the actual query reads, especially as you're not escaping directly injected values from $_POST, so risk of breaking the SQL with unescaped characters as well as risk of SQL injection

Comment: Now stop using the old, deprecated MySQLI interface and learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: and where is  `$hal, $row` define?

Comment: thanks guys for help me, I will learn to MySQLi or PDO

Comment: There are tutorials to learn from the beginning about the PDO

Comment: Use `  backticks  for   ```tbl_permintaan ``` echo your query and run in mysql

Answer (score 0):

you join many tables you must a write value tablePrefixes

example sql:

```
$userSql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_permintaan` AS `tp` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_kegiatan` AS `tk` ON `tk`.`id_kegiatan` = `tp`.`id_k` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_souvenir` AS `ts` ON `ts`.`id_souvenir` = `tp`.`id_s` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_loker` AS `tl` ON `tl`.`id_loker` = `tp`.`pt_pengirim` 
WHERE `tp`.`tgl` BETWEEN '" . $mulai . "' AND '" . $akhir . "' LIMIT " . $hal.", " " . $row . ";";
```

WARNING:
and you must validate and escape your values as php

you maybe catch syntax error on the future

NOTICE:

```
$userQry = mysql_query($userSql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query permintaan salah : ".mysql_error()); 
        var_dump($userQry);
```

mysql_query as deprecated on php5.5

please use PDO 
and try catch for debugging sql